# Symfony 3.3 : Array from controller to command with The Process component?

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to send a array from my controller to a command ?

My controller method and the array var :

```
$myArray = array("foo"=>"foo", "bar" => "bar");
$process = new Process('php ../bin/console app:my-command'); //how to send myArray
$process->start();
```

My command :

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->writeln([
        'Show my array below'
    ]);

    //print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to abstract the functionality in your command into a dedicated service and then use the service from the command and from the controller.

Comment: Thanks for you reply : ) 
In the concrete case, my controller receives a user file that I format and that I import into my database.
But the import is too long so I wanted to create a sub process (with Process component) to import. And I do not know how to pass the variable users (the array) to the command from my controller.

Comment: You can serialize the array and then just pass it as a regular argument.

Comment: like that : `$process = new Process('php ../bin/console app:my-command ' . $mySerializedVar);`
It doesn't work :/ I have this error : _The command &quot;php ../bin/console app:eligible-user a:1:{s:4:&quot;test&quot;;s:4:&quot;test&quot;;}&quot; failed._

Comment: Probably need a bit of encoding: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php The fact that this is turning out to be a pain probably indicates you should not be doing it.

Comment: It works !!! Thank to you Cerad ! : )

Comment: If you need a command, I would suggest to use a queue system like rabbit or whatever and let a consumer do this: you fill a (so called) "message" with the array then push (or publish) the message to the queue.